# How to use Firebase Cloud Firestore references with clean code?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So, I'm using Firebase Cloud and I have three references that I go through until I get my data.

this issue made me create 3 anonymous nested classes- which looks horrible, hard to follow and probably hard code to maintain.

I've added that code, I hope for your advice - how should I clean it up?

```
db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getUid())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            if (document.exists()) {
                                ((DocumentReference)document.get("Users_Project")).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                            if (document.exists()) {
                                                ((DocumentReference) document.get("Project_Schedule")).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                                            if (document.exists()) {
                                                                //we got the data!!!!
                                                                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                                                            } else {
                                                                Log.d(TAG, "No such document as projectschedule ref");
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            } else {
                                                Log.d(TAG, "No such document as projectschedule");
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "No such document as userproj");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: create appropriate methods for each call backs

Comment: can you please elaborate? show me a small piece of code so I'll get the idea? @MiteshMachhoya

Comment: You also might change your database schema / duplicate some data in order to make a single database call.

Comment: You should learn how to use the Task objects returned by the async methods.  You can chain together their results. It is technically more clean than the accepted answer.  There is a 4 part blog series here.  https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like  this :

```
db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getUid())
        .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                callback1(document);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document as userproj");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});

    private void callback1(DocumentSnapshot document)
    {
        ((DocumentReference)document.get("Users_Project")).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    callback2();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void callback2(DocumentSnapshot document)
    {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document.exists()) {
            ((DocumentReference) document.get("Project_Schedule")).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        callback3();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document as projectschedule");
        }
    }

    private void callback3(DocumentSnapshot document)
    {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document.exists()) {
            //we got the data!!!!
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document as projectschedule ref");
        }
    }
```